# copy files between datastores esxi 4 VHDs take full size not only used size?

Tags: vmware, virtualization, virtual-machine, esxi

when copy VMs between 2 NAS storages it take the full VHD size not the only used one. how to fix this

Answer (score 0):

You could cold storage-vmotion the VM files to another volume on the target NAS storage and specify 'thin-disk' format.